# Properties of LU decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I am given a matrix $A$ to decompose onto its $LU$ form. From this I find that $PA = LU$ where $P$ is a permutation matrix. Now the problem is that they define a matrix $B$ as $B = U^TAL^T$ and ask to find the $LU$ of $B$ without additional computations. Anyone can give me a tip where to start? I get that by substituting $A$ into $B$ the last part will be an upper triangular matrix, but can't get a way to make the lower triangular part.

Comment: You can't if row switches are necessary.

Comment: $PA = LU$ is usually considered an LU factorization *with pivoting*, while an LU factorization (without the mention of pivoting) is usually just $A = LU$. What is the exact text of your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Define the matrices

$$P = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}, \ L = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\l_{21}&1\end{pmatrix}, \ U = \begin{pmatrix} u_{11}&u_{12}\\0&u_{22}\end{pmatrix}$$

Substituting now $A=P^{-1}LU$ in $B=U^T A L^T$ gives $B=(U^T P^{-1}L) (U L^T)$.

Using the property that the set of upper triangular matrices is closed under multiplication,

The matrix $UL^T$ is itself an upper triangular matrix.

Thus we should check the matrix $M=U^T P^{-1}L$ which gives

$$M
= \begin{pmatrix} u_{11}&0\\u_{12}&u_{22}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\l_{21}&1\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 0&u_{11}\\u_{22}&u_{12}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\l_{21}&1\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix} l_{21}u_{11}&u_{11}\\u_{22}+l_{21}u_{12}&u_{12}\end{pmatrix}
$$

Which for generic parameters $l_{ij},u_{ij}$ is NOT a triangular matrix.

So this constitutes a counterexample to your question if $P\ne I$.

Answer (score 0):

By $LU$ factorization, $A = LU$, where $L$ is lower triangular and $U$ is upper triangular. If $B = U^{T}AL^{T}$, then we can write it as $B = (U^{T}L)(UL^{T})$. Note that $U^{T}L$ is lower triangular and $UL^{T}$ is upper triangular since product of lower (upper) triangular matrices is also lower (upper) triangular.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. It is as Got Gud said, it can't be done if there is a permutation matrix involved. I emailed my teacher as this was part three of one exercise but as it turns out it was totally unrelated to the previous parts of the exercise.